# Androidx and exoplayer

Tags: exoplayer, androidx

i try add `exoplayer` and `AndroidX` in may project  and got this error.

**error**

> Program type already present:
>   android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$CustomActionCallback
>
> Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present:
>   android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$CustomActionCallback,
>   sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

**gradle.properties**

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
//support library
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
//android architector componet
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.0.0-rc01"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-rc01"

//exo player
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.8.4'
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AndroidX is supported 'natively' since ExoPlayer 2.10.* (without using android.useAndroidX=true and android.enableJetifier=true)